# Weird behaviour of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

As you see in the GIF attached the UICollectionView works fine but the images in the cells are not stable (first you see one image and then the image change to the right image).

GIF example:
http://d.pr/i/ZccO

The refresh trigger:

```
self?.productsCollectionView.reloadData()
```

The collectionView function who create each cell:

```
    // make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // Check if need to load more battles
    if indexPath.item + Constants.bufferToLoad >= (Constants.pageSize * self.page) && Constants.pageSize * self.page < self.totalProducts {
        self.page += 1
        self.getProducts(false)
    }
    var cell:UICollectionViewCell?
    if self.isLoading && indexPath.item == self.products.count-1 {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Constants.loadigCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? LoadingCollectionViewCell
        (cell as! LoadingCollectionViewCell).activityView.startAnimating()
    } else {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Constants.cellName, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? SavedProductCollectionViewCell
        let productCell = cell as! SavedProductCollectionViewCell
        productCell.product = self.products[indexPath.item]
    }

    return cell!
}
```

This how I set image for each CollectionViewCell:

```
    var product:Product! {
    didSet {
        self.updateUI()
    }
}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

func updateUI() {
    self.productImage.loadImageFromURLString(self.product.mainImage!,placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeHolder"))
    self.productNameLabel.text = self.product?.name
    self.productPriceLabel.text = self.product?.price
    self.setPicks()
}
```

Comment: what you are seeing on your GIF is how the reusable cells are working in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Cells are reused. When a reused cell is returned it will still contain the old image until the load of the new image has completed. You should either set the image to `nil` or some placeholder image in `cellForItemAtIndexLath` or in the cell's `prepareForReuse` method.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
   self.productImage = nil
   self.productNameLabel.text = ""
   self.productPriceLabel.text = ""
}
```

Comment: Hey, but the images I see before are not the old image of the cell, it happens every refresh

Comment: Cells won't be reused in the same order, so you are getting *an old image* not necessarily the image that was in that position previously

Comment: Can you please write a code snippet you recommend me to add ? I tried to set the productImage to null but same weird behavior happens

Comment: Your code snippet return me an error because "loadImageFromURLString " dont work with nil, self.productImage.image = nil is not returing an error but the problem is the same